# Is there a Google 3d Warehouse API?

Tags: google-api, sketchup

Does anyone know if there is an official or unofficial API for Google 3D warehouse. I know of the iPhone app [NaviCAD](http://www.navicad.com/NaviCAD/Welcome.html), which shows Collada models from Google Warehouse - it has search, most-viewed, most-recent functionality; so I guess it is using some sort of API to get that data. But I couldn't find any auch api after searching around. Do you know if there is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck; from Google Sketchup API Blog:

- Removed Client Warehouse SDK from the package.  If you need support
  on this please post your contact info to the SDK support group.